# How do you change the Universe?

Tags: starbound

In Starbounds files, there are 2 files:

```
Starbound\starbound.config
```

and

```
Starbound\assets\default_configuration.config
```

In both files this entry exists:

> "rootKey" :
>   "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",

When I change this to a value like

```
"rootKey" : "KimJongIlIsOurGroriousLeader"
```

Starbound crashes.

So how do I change the universe seed correctly?

Comment: That rootkey value looks like it is the result of some hashing function, and are you sure editing the "rootKey" is the way to changing the universe seed?

Comment: I have the exact same rootKey.  If my assumptions are right, then this might be a part of Starbound's public key infrastructure.  The key is part of the authentication section, so I'll be submitting an answer shortly.

Comment: @Assylum Where did you find that editing this key would result in a new universe seed?

Comment: @Slurpee You would assume a file named `default_configuration` would be the same for everyone, would you not?

Comment: @3ventic Nah, common sense left a long time ago. :P

Comment: @Arperum http://www.reddit.com/r/starbound/comments/1sdajs/what_starbound_is_doing_wrong/cdwsiw7?context=3 I saw it there, when someone said he wanted a different universe.

Comment: Admit it, the only reason you asked this question was for the question title.

Comment: *♪I could chaaa-aaaa-aaange the world~, I would be the sunlight in your universe~♬*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rootKey that you are changing is, to the best of my knowledge, Starbound's [root certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate), which identifies Starbound's [certificate authority (CA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Authority).  This is all fancy computer speak for knowing where your computer's photo ID comes from.  Not being able to identify the CA results in a failed authentication, which makes the game crash.

There is no way to change the universe as a whole, but coordinates to planets are like Minecraft seeds.  If you want to go to the same planet as someone, you can use their coordinates.  Unfortunately due to the way planets generate, using coordinates only changes the planet's biome, and does not affect dungeon and/or ore spawns.

Source: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/starbound/comments/1ci6af/is_the_universe_uniquely_random_for_everyone/) and testing myself.

Comment: How come you can share coordinates and tell people where to look for a settlement to buy the good gear at then?

Comment: @James Not sure if settlements are considered dungeons to the game.

Comment: Well, I do not want to go the same planet, I just want a whole different universe that is different on other characters. That is the whole point of such games imho. This limit is very disappointing indeed.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the bit about the dungeons isn't true. There's an entire thread on the forums dedicated to sharing coordinates in order to find specific features.

Comment: @Assylum Why not just hit random? There are billions of available planets, it's not like you're going to go "Oh, I've been to this planet before. And this one. And this one..."

Comment: @SaintWacko Eventually this will happen.

Comment: @Assylum I'm not sure you appreciate the sense of scale. Assuming that SaintWacko's estimate of billions of planets is correct (though it may not be), even if there were only 1 billion planets and you only spent 1 second on each planet, it would take you 31.6 years of playing this game to see every one.  I'll leave it to Math.SE to figure out how long you'd have to play to have a non-trivial chance to hit Random and see 3 planets you've already visited 3 times in a row.

Comment: @Sterno How you appreciate my wish first? I just want a universe that is different from everyone elses. So my shit is on other places than for everyone else. And I don't need to be careful about spoilers.

Comment: @Assylum I'm 100% hoping there is an answer to your question that makes what you ask possible. It's all upside and no downside to have that capability. I was just pointing out that mathematically, running into the same planets randomly is not a likely occurence.

Comment: @Sterno I was wrong. There aren't billions of planets available. There are [quadrillions](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/a-little-perspective-on-the-size-of-starbound.27178/#post-1063769)

Answer (score 0):

The rootKey seems to be a [base64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) binary blob. Simply changing it to an arbitrary string won't work, and using a base64 encoded string is also unlikely to work.

It also doesn't appear to be the universe seed given that it's not in a per universe configuration file but in the starbound configuration file. There does not currently seem to be a known way to change the universes seed.